# Half-point size fonts in LaTeX

Tags: fontsize

How can I get a half point size in LaTeX? Many books use 10.5 pt. Setting point size to 10.5 seems to have no effect. Is there a package that can do that?

Comment: Have you tried something like `\fontsize{10.5}{12}\selectfont` (note the addition of `\selectfont` to "activate" the font) with a scalable font that has a `10.5pt` size (like [`lmodern`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lm))? If yes, then show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that illustrates the problem. If no, try it and give some feedback.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 21):

Historically speaking fonts used by LaTeX came only in well-defined sizes and the intermediate sizes were not available or only if you compiled them yourself. For example Computer Modern Roman existed in 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14.4 and a few others.

LaTeX knows what sizes are available for a certain font family, and if you you are using it out of the box it uses Computer Modern and the half points sizes aren't available. If use use Type 1 fonts then typically all sizes can be used and something like `\fontsize{9.5}{11}\selectfont` gives you the desired results.

The underlying mechanics are a little complicated: The LaTeX Companion devotes a whole chapter on how this all works and how NFSS (New Font Selection Scheme) is set up for new fonts. You can also look at [fntguide.pdf](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf) that explains the technique behind it.