# Palatino font size

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I'm using Palatino for my dissertation, but 10pt is too small and 11pt is too large (looks childish). I would like to select something in between. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Edit: following the other threads, there seem to be three answers:

1. (`pdflatex`, 11pt `memoir`, `fix-cm`, renew `\normalsize`): this only changes `\normalsize` (so not `\small`, `\huge`, etc.)

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{memoir}
   \renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{ppl}
   \usepackage{fix-cm}
   \renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10.5pt}{12.5pt}\selectfont}
   \begin{document}
   {\tiny This is tiny}\\
   {\scriptsize This is script size}\\
   {\footnotesize This is footnote size}\\
   {\small This is small}\\
   {\normalsize This is normal size}\\
   {\large This is large}\\
   {\Large This is larger}\\
   {\LARGE This is very large}\\
   {\huge This is huge}\\
   {\Huge This is very huge}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. (`pdflatex`, 11pt `memoir`, `fix-cm`, `relscale`): this doesn't work at all (since you would need to use `\relscale{0.96}` whenever changing from `\normalsize` to `\small` or something)

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{memoir}
   \renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{ppl}
   \usepackage{fix-cm,relsize}
   \begin{document}
   \relscale{0.96}
   {\tiny This is tiny}\\
   {\scriptsize This is script size}\\
   {\footnotesize This is footnote size}\\
   {\small This is small}\\
   {\normalsize This is normal size}\\
   {\large This is large}\\
   {\Large This is larger}\\
   {\LARGE This is very large}\\
   {\huge This is huge}\\
   {\Huge This is very huge}
   \end{document}
   ```
3. (`lualatex`, 11pt `memoir`): this changes all type sizes (`\normalsize`, `\small`, `\huge`, etc.)

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{memoir}
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont[Scale=0.96]{Palatino Linotype}
   \begin{document}
   {\tiny This is tiny}\\
   {\scriptsize This is script size}\\
   {\footnotesize This is footnote size}\\
   {\small This is small}\\
   {\normalsize This is normal size}\\
   {\large This is large}\\
   {\Large This is larger}\\
   {\LARGE This is very large}\\
   {\huge This is huge}\\
   {\Huge This is very huge}
   \end{document}
   ```

For example in my case, `\normalsize` was 10.91pt and afterwards 10.46pt. Perfect! Note also that in the third option, the system's Palatino font is used, while in the first two, URW Palladio is used. To conclude I would say that `lualatex` (or perhaps also `xelatex` etc.) is the way to go. The `\usepackage[scale=0.95]{tgpagella}` option mentioned in the comments also works, but this is specific to the font package.

However, there is still an issue remaining: how to change the math type size? I'm using `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: Check out this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83851/half-point-size-fonts-in-latex

Comment: If you don't need math, you can use `tgpagella` that accepts a "scale" option: `\documentclass[11pt]{article}` and then `\usepackage[scale=0.95]{tgpagella}` will set up the document with the parameters for 11pt size, but the font would be at 10.5; it's common to have a wider interline with Palatino.

Comment: Remember your supervisor's eyes may not be as good as yours. Using an 11 or 12 point size may be worth your while....

Comment: Perhaps the user needs to change their name to  Goldi-wox.  There's a great book in here somewhere... "Goldi-wox and the three fonts."  10.5 is "just right."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use also TeX Gyre Pagella Math:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Scale=0.96]{TeXGyre Pagella}
\setmathfont[Scale=0.96]{TeXGyrePagellaMath-Regular}
\begin{document}
{\tiny This is tiny}\\
{\scriptsize This is script size}\\
{\footnotesize This is footnote size}\\
{\small This is small}\\
{\normalsize This is normal size}\\
{\large This is large}\\
{\Large This is larger}\\
{\LARGE This is very large}\\
{\huge This is huge}\\
{\Huge This is very huge}


\[ \int\limits_1^\infty \frac1{x^2}\mathrm{d}x=1 \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This also seems to work: `\makeatletter
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{10.5}{8}{6} 
 \makeatother`