# Decreasing the font size in one node in a TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a diagram in which the font size for a node containing the measure of an angle is too big.  What is the default font size for a node?  What is the font size, in units of `pt`, for the specification `font=\footnotesize` in a node command?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%A triangle is to be drawn on the Cartesian plane.
\coordinate (E) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (0,{(4/3)*sqrt(3)});
\coordinate (D) at (4/3,0);
\coordinate (B) at ($(A)!{(8/3)*1cm}!90:(D)$);
\coordinate (C) at ($(D)!{(8/3)*1cm}!-90:(A)$);

\node[anchor=-75, inner sep=0] at ($(A) +({-75+180}:0.15)$){$A$};
\node[anchor=-75, inner sep=0] at ($(B) +({-75+180}:0.15)$){$B$};
\node[anchor={-75+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(C) +(-75:0.15)$){$C$};
\node[anchor={-75+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(D) +(-75:0.15)$){$D$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at (0,-0.15){$E$};


\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\draw (A) -- (E);
\draw (D) -- (E);


\draw node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(A)!0.5!(E)$) +(-0.15,0)$){$4\sqrt{3}$};


%A right-angle mark is drawn at D.
\coordinate (U) at ($(D)!3mm!45:(C)$);
\draw[dash dot] (U) -- ($(D)!(U)!(C)$);
\draw[dash dot] (U) -- ($(D)!(U)!(A)$);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at E.
\coordinate (V) at ($(E)!3mm!45:(D)$);
\draw[dash dot] (V) -- ($(E)!(V)!(D)$);
\draw[dash dot] (V) -- ($(E)!(V)!(A)$);

\draw[draw=blue] ($(A) +(-90:0.7)$) arc (-90:-60:0.7);
\node[anchor=west, rotate=-75, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(A) +(-75:0.8)$){$30^{\circ}$};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It depends. `\footnotesize` is not an absolute size in pts (and pts are not absolute either, of course). Rather, it is relative to the default font size for the document. There is no default font size for nodes generally. If you just say `\tikz{\node {whatever};}` you'll get the default size which, again, will depend on your document and the context within that document.

Comment: Just write `\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]`, or when you are using `\usepackage{anyfontsize}` you can write `\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\fontsize{20}{8}\selectfont]`.

Comment: @Giorgi If `\footnotesize` is too big, `\small` will only be worse, surely?

Comment: @cfr  What is the size of the text that is typeset in `\footnotesize` with respect to the font of the file?

Comment: See also [What point (pt) font size are \Large etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599)

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  Thanks for suggesting the web site.  For `12pt` font, text is typeset in `10.95pt` font using `\small`, `10pt` font using `\footnotesize`, `8pt` font using `\scriptsize`, and `6pt` font using `\tiny`.  My guess is that this give me enough variety.  In case I would like to have text in a node command typeset in `9pt` font, for example, please tell me the syntax.

Comment: See e.g. [Half-point size fonts in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83859) and [LaTeX -- specify font point size?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48276): `\fontsize{9pt}{11pt}\selectfont`. The second number is the baselineskip.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.   I see that the command to specify the font is `\fontsize{size}{skip}` and that it is suggested that "the baselineskip should be 1.2 times the font size."  If the node consists of text on a single line, what would you suggest for the `skip`?  How would I implement this font specification in the command `\node[anchor=-75, inner sep=0] at ($(A) +({-75+180}:0.15)$){$A$};` from my code?

Comment: 1) No idea about the skip value. 2) same way you would implement `\small` etc. I think, i.e. `\node[anchor=-75, inner sep=0,font=\fontsize{x}{y}\selectfont] at ($(A) +({-75+180}:0.15)$){$A$};`, or put it in the node text itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no answer to the question as stated. Not only is a `pt` relative to the font, but the meaning of commands such as `\footnotesize` depends on the class and, typically, on the font size option if the class offers the option of different sizes.

There is no default font size for nodes independent of everything else i.e. only in the sense that there is a default size for normal text etc. It picks up the document defaults and is context-sensitive.

`amsart.cls` uses `10pt` by default and defines it in the following way

```
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\def\@mainsize{10}\def\@ptsize{0}%
  \def\@typesizes{%
    \or{5}{6}\or{6}{7}\or{7}{8}\or{8}{10}\or{9}{11}%
    \or{10}{12}% normalsize
    \or{\@xipt}{13}\or{\@xiipt}{14}\or{\@xivpt}{17}%
    \or{\@xviipt}{20}\or{\@xxpt}{24}}%
  \normalsize \linespacing=\baselineskip
}
```

`\footnotesize` is defined as `\Small` which is defined as the fourth of the text sizes i.e. `{8}{10}`. So 8pt font with a 10pt baseline skip.

I have no idea why this is supposed to be helpful information.

Comment: I saw a comment from Frank Mittelbach in a response to another post.  He said that there is a chapter in The LaTeX Companion book discussing fonts available in LaTeX.  So, knowing something about font selection is helpful.  Probably, I will just use the commands `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, and `\small` to specify fonts.   You said that `\footnotesize` is defined as `\Small`.  Why would there be two commands to typeset the same font?  (Is `\Small` the same as `\small`?)

Comment: Also, knowing that the unit of `pt` is relative to the font and the class may be relevant - maybe not in coding but in comments in posts about font selection.  I want to at least give the pretense that I know what I am talking about.

Comment: `\footnotesize` is a standard size. `\Small` is specific to the AMS classes. `\small` is different, I believe. I suspect the double-naming is for historical reasons and to make sure standard LaTeX code does something appropriate i.e. it doesn't break if you switch to `amsart` from `article`.

Comment: `pt` is not relative to the font, it is 1/72.27  of an inch. the font specified units are `em` and `ex`.