# Any way to get 10.5 pt?

Tags: fonts, size

LaTeX offers 10pt or 11pt, but many books are published using 10.5 pt. Is there any way of getting 10.5 pt in LaTeX?

Comment: Yes. Read this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83851/half-point-size-fonts-in-latex  You will need to use Type I fonts.